# Not able to run php files on apache server using NetBeans IDE

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, php, netbeans

I want to create a php project using NetBeans IDE. I have set a LAMP server on my ubuntu 14.04. So I had to configure the IDE to copy files automatically to the apache server.I followed this - https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/project-setup.html#localServer

But the IDE **doesn't have permission to create folder** or any files on the apache server(var/www/html/) How do I proceed? The dialog box is giving me a warning saying "The folder cannot be created" and disabling the "next" and "finish" option so that I cannot go further. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

The question is too old. But I will answer it anyway.

You need to change the permissions of that directory.

```
sudo chmod 777 /var/www/html/
```